# What is the actual mechanism when we used VPN on HTTPS

Tags: tls, vpn

Will the VPN intercept the client's connection and read client's sending content or insert something else into clients's sending content? What is the actual process when we used VPN to access to one HTTPS website?

Comment: Why don't you read the basics of VPN first? There are plenty of tutorials on the web. If you have specific question, then people will surely answer it.

Comment: Actually, most of the websites mainly talked about using VPN over HTTP, this definitely improve the security. But, I cannot tell what exactly happened if people used VPN on HTTPS, would people using VPN over HTTPS have impact on overall security compared to just using HTTPS without VPN?

Comment: @Jeff Do you mean visiting a HTTPS website through a VPN tunnel?

Comment: @ Arminius Yes, I am confused about the actual process of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're simply sending your encrypted web traffic through the VPN tunnel. The VPN doesn't care if it's HTTPS or any other protocol. They just forward your traffic.

So, if you visit an HTTPS site through a VPN...

- Your [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) sees how you establish a connection to the VPN provider. They see the VPN server's IP which you're connecting to and can observe the handshake. Afterwards, they see how you exchange encrypted data which they can't decrypt or inject malicious packets into.
- The VPN provider sees the IP of the website you're visiting. They can observe your TLS handshake with the web server and due to [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) they most likely also see the server's hostname. Afterwards, when you're interacting with the website, they only see you exchange encrypted data which they can't tamper with.

You'll probably also issue a DNS query which, if it is configured to go through the VPN, is only visible to the VPN provider and not your ISP. Also, this is assuming a correct setup with certificate checks. That is, your VPN client needs to verify that the certificate provided by the VPN server is legitimate (to ensure your ISP didn't tamper with it) and your browser needs to verify that the certificate provided by the website is legitimate (to ensure your VPN provider didn't tamper with it).

Somewhat related:

- [Can a VPN decrypt my SSL traffic?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20948/can-a-vpn-decrypt-my-ssl-traffic) (They can't, unless you ignore certificate warnings.)

Comment: GREAT. What happened if the VPN provider send me a self-signed certificate? So, is it safe to say VPN provider cannot do anything harm to my content if I visited one HTTPS website?

Comment: @Jeff 1. If the VPN provider sends you a certificate you don't recognize, it could be your ISP or someone in your network MITMing you. 2. Yes, if you're using an up-to-date browser to visit an HTTPS website (while going through a VPN), the VPN provider knows which site you're connecting to, but they don't know the content you're viewing and they can't modify the encrypted traffic. (E.g. they know you're on Facebook, but they can't read or modify your messages.)